# Video to the right of the page

Tags: html, css, video

I am learning html, css and web development i am trying to play videos saved in my folder in the html page created. i have a problem. I am able to get header, navigation bar but my video is going to the bottom of the navigation bar, actually it should come right to the navigation bar.

Below is the code can you let me know where i need to make changes for the video to appear in the right of the navigation bar.

my html code below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
  <head>
  <title>Videos</title>
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="videos.css">
  </head>


<body>
   <header>
  <nav>
  <h1> Main logo </h1>
   <ul id="nav"> 
    <li><a class="homeblack" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="homered" href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>

 </ul>
 </nav>
 </header>
 <div class="divider"></div>
 <div>

<ul>
 <li><a href="#">education videos </a></li>
 <li><a href="#">film videos</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">other videos </a></li>
</ul>
 <div id="content"> Contents
<video controls width="250" height="160"> 
<source src="videoplayback.mp4" />
</video> 
<!-- <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mLe1pZ7w0v0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
</div>
</div>






    <!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

my css code below

```
* {
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
}


body{
  margin: 0;
 }

header {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 0px 6px 40px;
  height: 50px;
}

header h1 {
 display: inline;
 font-family: 'Oswald',sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 32px;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

nav ul{
  display: inline;
 padding: 0px;
float: left;
}

nav ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type:none;
 color: white;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 15px;
}

nav ul li a{
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#nav {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.homered{
 background-color: red;
 padding: 30px 10px 25px 10px;

}

.divider{
 background-color: red;
 height: 5px;

}

.homeblack:hover{
 background-color: blue;
 padding: 30px 10px 25px 10px;
}
div{
 width:250px;
 height:666px;
 background:#1A8DA9;
}
div a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
 padding:20px;
 padding-right:100px
}
div ul li{
 list-style-type:none;
 display:block;
 padding :15px;

 border-bottom:1px solid #236D7F;
 }
 div ul li :hover{
  background:#4097AD;
  transition:linear all 0.40s;
  margin-left:10px;
 }
 div ul li a:hover{
  color:black;
 }

#content{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    margin-left: 165px;
    position: 5px;
    float: right ;

 }
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with javascript..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your navbar in container with float: left value, also video must be wrapped in container with float: left. Look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xevaLaqq/1/) for example on js fiddle.

```
     <body>
     <header>
    <nav>
    <h1> Main logo </h1>
   <ul id="nav"> 
    <li><a class="homeblack" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="homered" href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
 </header>
 <div class="divider"></div>
 <div id="navBar">

<ul>
 <li><a href="#">education videos </a></li>
 <li><a href="#">film videos</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">other videos </a></li>
</ul>
 <div id="content"> Contents

<!-- <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mLe1pZ7w0v0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
</div>
</div>
 <video controls width="250" height="160"> 
<source src="videoplayback.mp4" />
</video> 






    <!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    </body>
  </html>
* {
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
}


body{
  margin: 0;
 }

header {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 0px 6px 40px;
  height: 50px;
}

header h1 {
 display: inline;
 font-family: 'Oswald',sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 32px;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

nav ul{
  display: inline;
 padding: 0px;
float: left;
}

nav ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type:none;
 color: white;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 15px;
}

nav ul li a{
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#nav {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.homered{
 background-color: red;
 padding: 30px 10px 25px 10px;

}

.divider{
 background-color: red;
 height: 5px;

}

.homeblack:hover{
 background-color: blue;
 padding: 30px 10px 25px 10px;
}
div{
 width:250px;
 height:666px;
 background:#1A8DA9;
}
div a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
 padding:20px;
 padding-right:100px
}
div ul li{
 list-style-type:none;
 display:block;
 padding :15px;

 border-bottom:1px solid #236D7F;
 }
 div ul li :hover{
  background:#4097AD;
  transition:linear all 0.40s;
  margin-left:10px;
 }
 div ul li a:hover{
  color:black;
 }

#content{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    margin-left: 165px;
    position: 5px;
    float: right ;

 }
 #navBar {
   float: left;
 }
 video {
   float: left;
 }
```

Comment: i am able to get video right of my side navigation bar exactly what i wanted. I have one more thing to check i have put some 5 videos i see all are overlapped on eachother how to arrange it one by one down side like a list. do i have to use li element or any other things.